# How to focus an opened b-collapse?

Tags: css, background, focus, background-color

How can I focus the opened collapse button?

```html
<template v-for"index in indexes">
  <b-btn v-b-toggle="'collapse' + index" variant="primary">Toggle Collapse</b-btn>
  <b-collapse :id="'collapse' + index">
    <b-card>Collapse contents Here</b-card>
  </b-collapse>
</template>
```

Like this:

[image: Focused Button]

I used `.btn:focus` and changed the background color to show what I mean. The problem is when i click somewhere else, the button isn't focused anymore.